# Find centrality measures (eigenvector, betweenness, closeness) for a directed and weighted graphs (python)

Tags: networkx, directed-graph, network-analysis, weighted-graph, node-centrality

## **Find centrality measures (eigenvector, betweenness, closeness) for a directed and weighted graphs (python)

## **

I am trying to score Sustainable development goals (SDGs), the nodes of my network, using centrality measures.
There are examples for literature doing so for undirected unweighted or weighted network, but never for directed and weighted networks.

I have used networkX to score the SDGs, assigning weight (reverse weight, since for my case higher weight is positive) through edge attribute and I use a DiGraph. however, I am aware that eigen, closeness and betweenness centralities give problem on directed graphs, so i was wondering whether you know of any python package that has inbuilt functions to handle such measures for weighted and directed graphs

Moreover, the graph I am constructing is not properly a DiGraph but rather a multigraph with the possibility of both directed and undirected edges i.e.

sdg 2.2 --> sdg 1.1
but also
sdg 2.2 -- sdg 1.1

however, i think it might be even harder to calculate centrality with a multigraph..
do you have any suggestion?